# Issue on Fitting Highcharts.js in Bootstrap 3 Panels

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having trouble on fitting highchart.js charts in Bootstrap 3 Panels located in Tab panes. Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/yhkbovkj/1/) and let me know what I am doing wring here?

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>

</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home" style="padding:20px;">Please Visit The Chart Pane</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Chart 1</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="" id="chart-box-1" style="width: 100%; height: 300px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> 
  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Chart 2</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="" id="chart-box-2" style="width: 100%; height: 300px"></div>
  </div>
</div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Chart3</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="" id="chart-box-3" style="width: 100%; height: 300px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is mentioned [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.width) in the Highcharts documentation, you should set a width in your chart object.

For example :

```
var chart1;
$(function() {
  chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'chart-box-1',
      width: 700
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
    },
    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
    }]
  });
});
```

I updated your fiddle so you can check the result : http://jsfiddle.net/yhkbovkj/2/